# how to get filepaths of print jobs in queue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I would like to get the list of queued print jobs and their filepaths using C# in .NET 4. I looked at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Printing%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but didn't see anything regarding filepath. I tried the following code (modified from an example somewhere), hoping `job.Name` or `job.JobName` is what i am looking for, but it doesn't run:

calling `GetPrintJobInfoCollection()` always raises `NullReferenceException` when there is a job (printer is offline, so the job is always waiting in queue). The exception does not occur when jobs are deleted from queue (by clicking on the printer icon in lower right corner).

so 2 questions:

1. why `NullReferenceException`?
2. Any other ways to get queued filepaths if this method fails?

Thanks in advance!

```
public static void testPrinter()
{
    PrintQueueCollection printQueues = null;
    PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer();
    printQueues = printServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });

    foreach (PrintQueue printQueue in printQueues)
    {
        foreach (var job in printQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("jobname={0} name={1} size={2} status={3}", job.JobName, job.Name, job.JobSize, job.JobStatus));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Can you post the exception stack trace?

Comment: the line with `printQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection()` throws the `NullReferenceException`. just found out that it was caused by the printer being offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the exception only occurs when the printer is offline. When the printer is online, `job.Name` gives the filepath, while `job.JobName` only says "Print System Document".